# Why in the input type button the cursor is an arrow and not a hand?

Tags: css, xhtml, button

This question is because normally when you want to click a button or link the user expect a HAND in the cursor but in the case of input type="button" you get a cursor arrow , does any know why is this? is cause is inherit from base class input?? and all inputs have pointer cursor?

I Know a simple css lik {cursor:pointer} //make the work... but wait is not make more sense that instead of "cursor:pointer" would be {cursor:hand} //IE support this one.

Hope some have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it has no defined cursor style so it defaults to `default`

Comment: not so much inheriting as not inheriting anything, which is `default`

Answer (score 0):

The "hand" cursor originally arose because of single-click links.  And, in a web browser, the `<a>` element is *the* link element.

But, in other contexts (Windows forms, etc.), the default cursor (arrow pointer) can click on the buttons, so the browsers are just keeping UI consistent.

A browser could theoretically change the default cursor to a hand for `<input type="button">` elements.

But, `cursor:pointer;` makes more sense for CSS, because it doesn't necessarily have to be a hand image.  You can always change your cursors to another image, but the behavior (`pointer` in this case) defines what you call the cursor, not the image.